# RuntimeError with aiohttp persistent session

Tags: python, aiohttp

I just started with aiohttp and ran into an issue that I can't seem to figure out.

I create a persistent session.

`session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)`

```
async def fetch(url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        return await resp.json()

async def run():
    task = asyncio.create_task(fetch('https://someurl'))
    await task
```

When I call `run()` my program crashes with following traceback.

```
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

I don't get any traceback and the func executes fine when I don't use a persistent session. That is, `run` executes as expected when I define `fetch` as following.

```
async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as see:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.json()
```

Comment: `def run` is not `async`, so you can't use `await` inside it. Maybe the formatting of post is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I omitted `async` keyword while posting the question. I've made edits to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move `session = ...ClientSession` to inside `fetch`, you'd also be better off using `async with` when creating the session.

Something like

```
async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.json()

async def run():
    task = asyncio.create_task(fetch('https://someurl'))
    await task
```

**Updated, more complete example:**

```
class Foboar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None

    async def run(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)
        try:
            for url in all_my_urls:
                await self.fetch(url)
        finally:
            await self.session.close()

    async def fetch(self, url):
        async with self.session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.json()
```

Comment: This works but then I end up creating a new session for every request I make. How can I persist a session for reuse rather creating a new session everytime I call `fetch`

Comment: yes, so create the session in `run` and pass it to every `fetch` call. Look at the main example [here](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

Comment: As per https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#json-response-content, session context manager is not required which is what I am doing. Moreover, the approach you suggest still creates a new session whenever `run` is called. I want to create a `session` per-site like initializing `self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()` when my HttpClient is initialized.

Comment: sorry, I was hurrying, updated with a more complete example implementing `self.session`.

Comment: How is it different than my original question? After `run` is called, `self.session` will be bound to an instance of `aiohttp.ClientSession` and in my code I bind `session` to `aiohttp.ClientSession` before I call `run`. The only way I have been able to get my code to work is if I pass `timeout=None` but seeing other issues.

Comment: because you should create the session inside a coroutine to avoid warnings and get aiohttp to work properly. Your code example is somewhat messed up, but it looks like you're creating the session in the global context eg. outside a coroutine.

Comment: I have a class like `Foobar` in your example where session is set to initialize during class initialization (i.e `self._session = aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers)`). In your example, a new session object gets created whenever `run` is called. aiohttp docs is either ambiguous or they need to provide a better example on how one can create a persistent `session`, the doc says one should reuse the session but all the examples I have seen so far requires one to create a new `session` for every request.

Comment: Yes, the docs could be better, PR welcome. The point is that `session` is not recreated every time you call `fetch`, if it makes it clearer, rename `run` > `start` and remove the fetch calls from there, then call `fetch` (either from with in the class or from elsewhere) as many times as you like.

Comment: I get it that `run` is like an `init_session` that can be called from `__init__`

Comment: you can't call it from `__init__`, because it' not a coroutine. (well you could if the loop wasn't running, or you started a task, but that will just make your life more complicated).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving, i.e. `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` is because you initilize the `aiohttp.ClientSession` outside of a task (an async function).

Let me clarify with some code:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from typing import Any


def main() -> None:
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # This is not OK, not in a task!

    async def fetch(url: str) -> Any:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.json()

    # This will now raise a
    # RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
    asyncio.run(fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This solution is to move the code into a task (async function). Like so:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from typing import Any


async def main() -> None:
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()  # This is OK, in a task!

    async def fetch(url: str) -> Any:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()

    await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/")

    # Don't forget to close your session!
    await session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Better yet, use a context manager:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from typing import Any


async def main() -> None:
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        # Don't forget tough, the session, and thus this fetch is only valid for the
        # contexts duration.
        async def fetch(url: str) -> Any:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                return await resp.text()

        await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/")

    # As you "dedent", you end the context of the session, and can not be used anymore.

    # No need to close the session, the context manager takes care of that!
    # await session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Adjust the code for your needs, and you'll be good to go. [You can read more at my answer on a similiar question at the aiohttp github repository](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4932#issuecomment-1611759696).